# Pandas - How to identify nans while inside the apply function?

Tags: python, pandas

I am writing complex rules row-wise and for that, I am using df.apply. Inside this function, one of the conditions is to check if one of the values in the column MEASUREMENT is blank/null/nan. How do I do this? It seems really easy but I can't get it to work. I know I could use other vectorized methods to check for nans, but I need to write complex rules, so I am using df.apply.

My data looks like:

```
MEASUREMENT VALUE
Name1       0.1
Name2       0.2
            0.3
Name4       0.2
231         0.4
```

My code looks like this

```
func(row):
   if row['MEASUREMENT'] == np.NaN:
       print row['VALUE']

new_df = df.apply(func, axis=1)
```

It should print 0.3.

NOTES: 
MEASUREMENT column has mixed data types. I have tried loading it as str and by default, and the condition still doesn't work. I am using Python 3.7 as I installed Anaconda.

I have tried everything but cannot come to a solution. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: why not using .isnull or .isna?

Comment: @Wen-Ben That definitely works too. For me, it didn't work before because I was doing row['MEASUREMENT'].isna() instead of pd.isna(row['MEASUREMENT']).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`NaN` is not equal to any value, *including itself.* So you can check like this:

```
if row['MEASUREMENT'] != row['MEASUREMENT']:
```

However, in situations where the values are known to be numeric, a better (that is, more readable) way is `math.isnan()`.

```
from math import isnan
if isnan(row['MEASUREMENT']):
```

Comment: First one works great! I would have never guessed it.
Second one doesn't work as the column MEASUREMENT is mixed type and has strings too who error out when tested when isnan(). Thanks!

Comment: Good point, I've added a bit about values needing to be numeric.

Answer (score 3):

Writing something like:

```
if x == np.nan:
```

And then wondering why it doesn't work as intended is a common mistake.

When dealing with Pandas dataframes, one can also use `pandas.isnull()`, which according to [the documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.isnull.html) can deal with array-like objects.
The statement then becomes:

```
if pd.isnull(row['MEASUREMENT']):
```